# I have a nested function in a function but my code won't clear the display correctly. I am not getting an error in console?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function clearTheDisplayInitial()
    {
       $(document.getElementById('Resume')).hide();
       $(document.getElementById('CodingExamples')).hide();
       $(document.getElementById('AboutMe')).hide();
    }
    function clearTheDisplay()
    {
       $(document.getElementById('Resume')).fadeOut(900);
       $(document.getElementById('CodingExamples')).fadeOut(900);
       $(document.getElementById('AboutMe')).fadeOut(900);
       $(document.getElementById('mainMenu')).fadeOut(900);

    }
        $("#displayResume").click(function()
        {
            clearTheDisplayInitial();
            $(document.getElementById('Resume')).fadeIn(900);
        });
        $("#CodingExamples1").click(function()
        {
            clearTheDisplay();
           $(document.getElementById('AboutMe')).fadeIn(900);
        });
});
```

I can't get the screen to clear with the two methods. Console doesn't recognize that the functions exist. I do get the fade in features to work though

Comment: `$(document.getElementById('Resume')).fadeIn(900);` can be `$('#Resume').fadeIn(900);`, use the id selector

Comment: Those functions exist only inside of the callback for `$(document).ready()`. They aren't globals.

Comment: I just don't get why you are using `document.getElementById('Resume')` with jQuery. Especially inside of the jQuery function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend just declaring the functions outside of the `$(document).ready(function(){ .. });`

The console doesn't recognize that the functions exist because you are basically trying to make local functions.

```
function clearTheDisplayInitial() {
    $("#Resume, #CodingExamples, #AboutMe").hide();
}
function clearTheDisplay() {
    $("#Resume, #CodingExamples, #AboutMe, #mainMenu").fadeOut(900);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#displayResume").click(function() {
        clearTheDisplayInitial(); // you could just add $("#Resume, #CodingExamples, #AboutMe").hide(); here
        $("#Resume").fadeIn(900);
    });
    $("#CodingExamples1").click(function() {
        clearTheDisplay(); // you could just add $("#Resume, #CodingExamples, #AboutMe, #mainMenu").fadeOut(900); here
        $("#AboutMe").fadeIn(900);
    });
});
```

I simplified your code by the way. I hope you didn't really need the functions to be inside of the document ready function.